# Do I need azurerm_mssql_server for azurerm_mssql_database?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database, azure-rm

Currently I create my Azure SQL database like this:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  name                         = azurecaf_name.names.results["azurerm_mssql_server"]
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.default_rg.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.default_rg.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = var.mssql_admin_user
  administrator_login_password = var.mssql_admin_password
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sqldatabase" {
  name           = azurecaf_name.names.results["azurerm_mssql_database"]
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
  sku_name       = "Basic"
}
```

So I create a server and then a database - do I always need the server or is it somehow possible to directly create a database without creating a server first? Current way feels a little bit strange to me.

Comment: Why does it feel strange to have a server to host the database on? You can't create multiple databases on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for your mssql db instance a mssql server id is always required:

> server_id - (Required) The id of the MS SQL Server on which to create
> the database. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.